# Moving SVG objects with JavaScript blocks the Touchmove event when using removeChild

Tags: javascript, svg

When I try to move a SVG object it work's not when using removeChild(). It blocks also the touchmove event when moving.

**Pseudocode:**

```
id.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  if (selected == true) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveY = y;
    var n = document.getElementById("test"); // remove nodes
    while (n.lastChild) {
     n.removeChild(n.lastChild);
    }
    test.appendChild(createElementNS...); // add it again
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of SVG but of suppression of the element. messages do not arrive anymore. Look [Touch Move event don't fire after Touch Start target is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298828/touch-move-event-dont-fire-after-touch-start-target-is-removed)
The problem is described and solutions are proposed